# Insert bold in column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, json-formatting, column-formatting

How do I insert code so this will also become Bold?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Ev_x002e__x0020_sluttid] <=[$_x00c4_rende_x0020_p_x00e5_b_x00], '#ff0000', '#32CD32')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Ev_x002e__x0020_sluttid] <=[$_x00c4_rende_x0020_p_x00e5_b_x00], '#ff0000', '#32CD32')", 
    "font-weight": "bold" 
  }
}
```

**References**:

1. [CSS font-weight Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp).
2. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).